# cannot call post methods in asp

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I can only call to asp GET methods using ajax.
This is my JavaScript:

```
$scope.test = function () {
    var dataObject = {};
    dataObject.Company_Code = companyCode;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:31041/api/Location/test',
        data: $.param(dataObject),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
 .success(function (data) {    
 }).error(function () {
 });
}
```

And this is my WebAPI method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string test(Company_Details Company)
{
  return "11";
}
```

My `global.asax` settings:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

When I try to invoke this method I receive the following error:
[image]
and also i can invoke post method with URL parameters(`url: 'http://localhost:31041/api/Location/test?Name:123',`). but cannot pass data using `data: $.param(dataObject)`

Comment: Your getting a server error. So if you attach the debugger you should be able to see where the exception is coming from

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `[FromBody]` to the `Company_Detailss` parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public string test([FromBody]Company_Details Company)
{
  return "11";
}
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `Company_Details` and the code where you define your routing.

Comment: public partial class Company_Details
    {public string Company_Code { get; set; }
        public string Company_Prefix { get; set; }
        public string Company_Name { get; set; }
        public string Company_Addres { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Location")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public string test(Company_Details Company)
{
    return "11";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look like you need use **JSON.stringify** for your data object

```
method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:31041/api/Location/test',
        data: JSON.stringify($.param(dataObject))
```